# Checking a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is an example out of Anton *Elementary Linear Algebra*

> Consider the vectors $u = (1,2,-1)$ and $v = (6,4,2)$ in $R^3$. Show that $w = (9,2,7)$ is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.

The example starts like the following:

> In order for $W$ to be a linear combination of $u$ and $v$, there must be scalars $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $w = k_1u + k_2v$
>   So we have:
>   $\begin{align}
>  k_1 + 6k_2 = 9 \\
>  2k_1 + 4k_2 = 2 \\
> -k_1 + 2k_2 = 7
> \end{align}$

Now if I use Gaussian elimination on this I get:

$\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&6&9 \\ 
0&1&2 \\
0&0&-1
\end{array}
\right]$

Which, I thought was inconsistent. However using this matrix, the book finds $k_1 = 2$ and $k_2 = -3$. But how can they say this is a solution of the problem if it is an overdetermined system and none of the equations is a linear combintion of another equation? I thought the rule was that it would be inconsistent?

Comment: If you are just interested in showing that they are linear dependent, but the vector in a matrix as rows, use gaussian elimination and you will get that the rank is 2 (and not 3), therefore the set is not linear independent. Maybe you had an error calculating your gaussian elimination ?

Comment: You have a typo in your first equation. The right side should be $9$ and not $4$. Moreover in the augmented matrix you have a $-9$ instead of $+9$. Perhaps this lead you to incorrect subsequent steps. In fact, you can check that $w=-3u+2v$.

Comment: Ok, I have corrected it, but can we not just look at the system of equations and see that there are more equations than unknowns, as well, no equation is a linear combination of another equation, therefore this overdetermined system is inconsistent?

Comment: Yep, you are right @Mickey. Error indeed.

Comment: Yep, you are right @AnuregA. I did what you asked me to do and it did check out alright. I found my error. Cheers.